# Insertion of data into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to php I have created a php form that will insert data into the database my database name is Emp and the table name is info. I'm inserting using PDO. I have written a code to do this and it is getting executed without catching any errors, but the database is still empty. I have posted my code below please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
    try{
        echo $_POST['name'].", ".$_POST['age'].", ".$_POST['email'].", ".$_POST['name'].", ".$_POST['country'].", ". $_POST['city'] ;
        $user="root";
        $pass="root123";
                    $con=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Emp', $user, $pass);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $con->beginTransaction();
        //echo "INSERT INTO info(Empid,Ename,Age,Email,Country,City,Salary) VALUES('".$_POST['eid']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['country']."','".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['salary']."')";
        $num=$con->exec("INSERT INTO info(Empid,Ename,Age,Email,Country,City,Salary) VALUES('".$_POST['eid']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['country']."','".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['salary']."')");
        echo "<br>".$num." row added succesfully"; // this is displayed when I execute this but database is empty.
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Exception -> ';
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what happens when you run this query directly into your database?

Comment: You're starting a transaction with `beginTransaction()`, but it won't appear on the database until you finalise the transaction with `commit()`

Comment: Mike is right, you need to `commit` @user2655318

Comment: Additional note: please read the paragraph on PDO and bound parameters in this document to avoid SQL injectin: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either have to commit or rollback the transaction ..

changes made to the database via the PDO transactions are not committed until you end the transaction by calling `PDO::commit()` or `Calling PDO::rollBack()`

```
<?php
try{
    echo $_POST['name'].", ".$_POST['age'].", ".$_POST['email'].", ".$_POST['name'].", ".$_POST['country'].", ". $_POST['city'] ;
   ...
  $con->beginTransaction();
  ....
   $con->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
     $con->rollBack();
}
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter btw but you have typo here `$conn->commit();` and also we have the very same code in our answers. weird :/

Answer (score 2):

Since you have used `beginTransaction()`, you have to `commit` the changes. Add

```
$con->commit();
```

Reference: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

**Note:** Even though you are using PDO, you are still interpolating HTTP Request values without sanitization, that could be bad

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to `commit` and/or `rollBack` your code

```
<?php
    try{
        .
        . code
        .
        $con->beginTransaction();
        .
        . code
        .
        $num=$con->exec("INSERT INTO info (Empid,Ename,Age,Email,Country,City,Salary) VALUES('".$_POST['eid']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['country']."','".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['salary']."')");
        $con->commit(); // This is missing
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        $con->rollBack(); //  And this is missing
    }
?>
```